# After Migrating to New Server CSS and JS file not loading, also Backend Admin is not Accessible

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, js-css

I am using magento 1.9. `core_config_data` urls I have checked it was right, Deleted the cache folder from var, Permission is 777. Still css js are not loading, admin is not accessible.

In the local server it is working fine.

[image]

Comment: I think In you base url you forgot to add `foward slash (/)` in the end. Check the `core_config_table` and search for `base_url` in path and see its value `http://salesjooli.com/`

Comment: That is not the issue my friend. I have added the forward slash in both of the secure  and nonsecure urls in the database.

Comment: Checked in the incognito. Magento var/cache folder deleted.  Still no work

Comment: check uploaded files accessible for root user of that website.

Comment: added  chmod -R 777 permission on all the files and folders

Comment: user is also ubuntu in all files

Comment: have you checked `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` for default and store in `core_config_table` table?

Comment: Yes. forward slash is there

Comment: do you have multiple store view? Please open this `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` file  and check `getBaseUrl` method what this is returning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78237/discussion-between-kunj-and-sayantan-das).

Comment: please check .htaccess file is exist or not.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of secure base url and unsecure base url from admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check following,
Unsecure bade url, skin, media , JavaScript url 
Secure base url, skin, media, JavaScript url 
In core_config_data table.

The problem is it’s missing / after base url.

Also check if there is any rule in .htaccess against url.